# Many-to-many relationship only working one way in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relational-database

I don't know if anyone can help me as this is a little odd.

I have a moderately complicated set of relations in a database, which roughly has a structure something like this:

Delivery Director has Account Directors has Pods has Account Managers has Companies.

Therefore, Delivery Directors should have Companies.

This whole structure is working, all the way down to Companies, and then suddenly stops. The Delivery Director returns [] on companies.

```
class DeliveryDirector < User
  has_many :account_directors
  has_many :pods, through: :account_directors
  has_many :account_managers, through: :pods
  has_many :companies, through: :account_managers
end
```

And the company class looks like:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :account_manager
   has_one :pod, through: :account_manager
   has_one :account_director, through: :pod
   has_one :delivery_director, through: :account_manager
end
```

Like I say, everything is working. The Company even has a Delivery Director! It's just the DeliveryDirector.all.first.companies returns [].

If anyone could even just point me in the right direction, that would be great. There is no error message, and nothing seems to be going wrong at all.

Oh, in case it helps, here is the SQL generated by the query:

```
Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "users" ON "companies"."account_manager_id" = "users"."id" INNER JOIN "pods" ON "users"."pod_id" = "pods"."id" INNER JOIN "users" "account_directors_companies" ON "pods"."account_director_id" = "account_directors_companies"."id" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('AccountDirector') AND "account_directors_companies"."delivery_director_id" = $1  [["delivery_director_id", 2]]
```

Thanks!

Edit: Request for other models, schema

Pod:

```
class Pod < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :account_director
   has_many :account_managers
   has_many :companies, through: :account_managers
end
```

Account Manager:

```
class AccountManager < User
  belongs_to :pod
  has_one :account_director, through: :pod
  has_one :delivery_director, through: :account_director
  has_many :companies
end
```

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_10_19_141416) do


  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "officelocation"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "campaign_link"
    t.string "company_logo"
    t.string "website"
    t.integer "account_manager_id"
  end

  create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "location"
    t.bigint "company_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_images_on_company_id"
  end

  create_table "jwt_blacklist", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "jti", null: false
    t.index ["jti"], name: "index_jwt_blacklist_on_jti"
  end

  create_table "markets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "markets_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "market_id", null: false
    t.bigint "talent_manager_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "pods", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "account_director_id"
    t.integer "delivery_director_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "table_campaigns", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "company_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "iterations"
    t.integer "interviews"
    t.index ["company_id"], name: 
    "index_table_campaigns_on_company_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_table_campaigns_on_user_id"
 end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "jobtitle"
    t.string "linkedin"
    t.string "office"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "type"
    t.integer "team_lead_id"
    t.integer "delivery_director_id"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.bigint "pod_id"
    t.string "user_photo"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["pod_id"], name: "index_users_on_pod_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: 
     "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "table_campaigns", "companies"
  add_foreign_key "table_campaigns", "users"
end
```

And now adding Account Director:

```
class AccountDirector < User
  belongs_to :delivery_director
  has_one :pod
  has_many :account_managers, through: :pod
  has_many :companies, through: :account_managers
end
```

Comment: It looks good. Can you add `Pod`, `AccountManager` models and your database schema.

Comment: Hi, I added some more info: any idea what's going on? :(

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do your AccountManager and Company relationship works? Can you check if `account_manager.companies` works? And `pod.companies`  and `account_director.companies`?

Comment: Yep, those all work... it's so confusing!

Comment: sorry to bump this but if anyone has any neat ideas, I'd love to hear them. Absolutely at a loss over here...

Comment: Can you also show your `User` model?

Comment: And `AccountDirector`?

Comment: The User one doesn't have anything but Devise stuff in it... but I'll add Account Director...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Single Table Inheritance. 3 of your models: `DeliveryDirector`, `AccountDirector` and `AccountManager` are descendants of `User` model. When doing shallow request it works fine, but when you construct requests which involve all 3 models Rails cannot build the right query. If you try to project how to find all companies of a delivery director in terms of database, you will come to the chain of tables:

```
companies -> users (account managers) -> pods -> users (account directors) -> users (delivery directors)
```

The SQL query for your request may look like:

```
SELECT companies.* FROM companies
  INNER JOIN users AS account_managers ON companies.account_manager_id = account_managers.id
  INNER JOIN pods ON account_managers.pod_id = pods.id
  INNER JOIN users AS account_directors ON pods.account_director_id = account_directors.id
  INNER JOIN users AS delivery_directors ON account_directors.delivery_director_id = delivery_directors.id
WHERE delivery_directors.id = 2;
```

but obviously, Rails does not add `AS` clause to the query to distinguish user roles and uses `users` table name instead. To filter results it uses condition `"users"."type" IN ('AccountDirector')` which is not enough in your case, because in your query there should be also `AccountManager` (as a link between `pods` and `companies`).

Another sign that Rails is confused: despite correct association in your models Rails tries to use table `account_directors_companies` which you obviously do not have.

I would recommend to review your database schema and extract user roles and relationship between them into separate substances.

**UPDATE:**

For example, user authentication/registration data can be left in `users` table as it is now. All info about user roles and their relations can be moved to extra tables, backed up by models:

```
class DeliveryDirector < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :account_directors
  has_many :pods, through: :account_directors
  has_many :account_managers, through: :pods
  has_many :companies, through: :account_managers
end

class AccountDirector < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :pod
  has_many :account_managers, through: :pod
  has_many :companies, through: :account_managers
end

class AccountManager < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :companies
end
```

Each of these models has their own table in the database.

Thus, to fetch companies of delivery director you could call:

```
DeliveryDirector.find_by(user_id: user_id).companies
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help... is this really the right decision though?! Single Table Inheritance seems to match our use case completely. It seems strange we should have to give it up because Rails gets "confused". I tried to map it out with each user type being a separate entity and it got complicated very quickly...

Comment: See update to the answer. You don't have to clone user functionality among other models. Just extract user roles into separate classes.

Comment: And sorry, it doesn't look like STI is the right choice here. Look at table `users`. It incorporates fields from all roles, such as `delivery_director_id`, `pod_id`, etc. which are not used for user of another role

Comment: Really interesting! I've never thought of using belongs_to to extend functionality like this... is this called anything, can I read more about it somewhere...?

Comment: I don't think it has a special name... It's just refactoring. When your model becomes too bulky you can move part of business logic to another model, which you still can access from original model through your ActiveRecord association